# Reading VertNet .txt files

Tags: r

I am a beginner R user so I apologize in advance. I am attempting to read a .txt data file from VertNet.org into my workspace. I have attempted to load the .txt file like I have successfully done before but this method is not identifying all of the data columns present in the file.

```
Sciurus_carolinensis_total <- read.delim("Sciurus_carolinensis_total.txt")
```

Below is the code of the columns that I want in my final data frame.

```
Sciurus_carolinensis_total <- select(Sciurus_carolinensis_total, c(genus, specificepithet, sex, year, month, day, countrycode, stateprovince, county, decimallatitude, decimallongitude, lengthinmm, lengthtype))
```

Below is the top few rows of the .txt file. I wasn't sure if this would be the appropriate way to provide this information. Let me know if another format would be better.

```
type    modified    license rightsholder    accessrights    bibliographiccitation   references...
PhysicalObject      CC0         California Academy of Sciences. CAS Mammalogy (MAM). Recor...
PhysicalObject  2009-06-05 15:46:10.0   CC0         California Academy of Sciences. CAS M...
PhysicalObject  2019-08-25 10:42:36.0   http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zer...
PhysicalObject  2019-09-18 16:45:02.0   http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zer...
PhysicalObject  2018-02-28  https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/      ht...
```

The data above is truncated (each line is actually well over 1400 characters) and actually has embedded tabs, but the HTML here does not show that. Here's the results of `dput` for that text, not truncated:

```r
c("type\tmodified\tlicense\trightsholder\taccessrights\tbibliographiccitation\treferences\tinstitutionid\tcollectionid\tdatasetid\tinstitutioncode\tcollectioncode\tdatasetname\tbasisofrecord\tinformationwithheld\tdatageneralizations\tdynamicproperties\toccurrenceid\tcatalognumber\trecordnumber\trecordedby\tindividualcount\tsex\tlifestage\treproductivecondition\tbehavior\testablishmentmeans\toccurrencestatus\tpreparations\tdisposition\tassociatedmedia\tassociatedreferences\tassociatedsequences\tassociatedtaxa\tothercatalognumbers\toccurrenceremarks\torganismid\torganismname\torganismscope\tassociatedoccurrences\tassociatedorganisms\tpreviousidentifications\torganismremarks\tmaterialsampleid\teventid\tfieldnumber\teventdate\teventtime\tstartdayofyear\tenddayofyear\tyear\tmonth\tday\tverbatimeventdate\thabitat\tsamplingprotocol\tsamplingeffort\tfieldnotes\teventremarks\tlocationid\thighergeographyid\thighergeography\tcontinent\twaterbody\tislandgroup\tisland\tcountry\tcountrycode\tstateprovince\tcounty\tmunicipality\tlocality\tverbatimlocality\tminimumelevationinmeters\tmaximumelevationinmeters\tverbatimelevation\tminimumdepthinmeters\tmaximumdepthinmeters\tverbatimdepth\tminimumdistanceabovesurfaceinmeters\tmaximumdistanceabovesurfaceinmeters\tlocationaccordingto\tlocationremarks\tdecimallatitude\tdecimallongitude\tgeodeticdatum\tcoordinateuncertaintyinmeters\tcoordinateprecision\tverbatimcoordinates\tverbatimlatitude\tverbatimlongitude\tverbatimcoordinatesystem\tverbatimsrs\tfootprintwkt\tfootprintsrs\tgeoreferencedby\tgeoreferenceddate\tgeoreferenceprotocol\tgeoreferencesources\tgeoreferenceverificationstatus\tgeoreferenceremarks\tgeologicalcontextid\tearliesteonorlowesteonothem\tlatesteonorhighesteonothem\tearliesteraorlowesterathem\tlatesteraorhighesterathem\tearliestperiodorlowestsystem\tlatestperiodorhighestsystem\tearliestepochorlowestseries\tlatestepochorhighestseries\tearliestageorloweststage\tlatestageorhigheststage\tlowestbiostratigraphiczone\thighestbiostratigraphiczone\tlithostratigraphicterms\tgroup\tformation\tmember\tbed\tidentificationid\tidentificationqualifier\ttypestatus\tidentifiedby\tdateidentified\tidentificationreferences\tidentificationverificationstatus\tidentificationremarks\tscientificnameid\tnamepublishedinid\tscientificname\tacceptednameusage\toriginalnameusage\tnamepublishedin\tnamepublishedinyear\thigherclassification\tkingdom\tphylum\tclass\torder\tfamily\tgenus\tsubgenus\tspecificepithet\tinfraspecificepithet\ttaxonrank\tverbatimtaxonrank\tscientificnameauthorship\tvernacularname\tnomenclaturalcode\ttaxonomicstatus\ttaxonremarks\tlengthinmm\tlengthtype\tlengthunitsinferred\tmassing\tmassunitsinferred\tunderivedlifestage\tunderivedsex\tdataset_url\tdataset_citation\tgbifdatasetid\tgbifpublisherid\tdataset_contact_email\tdataset_contact\tdataset_pubdate\tlastindexed\tmigrator_version\thasmedia\thastissue\twascaptive\tisfossil\tisarch\tvntype\thaslength", "PhysicalObject\t\tCC0\t\t\tCalifornia Academy of Sciences. CAS Mammalogy (MAM). Record ID: urn:catalog:CAS:MAM:24943. Source: http://ipt.calacademy.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=mam (source published on 2019-07-23)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cas/mam?id=urn-catalog-cas-mam-24943\t\t\t\tCAS\tMAM\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t\turn:catalog:CAS:MAM:24943\t24943\tCBC3\tC. B. Clark\t\tfemale\tadult\t\t\t\t\tSN\t\t\t\t\t\tSFSU\tMeasurements: 17 1/2-7.9-2 1/4-0.75 in; no wt.  Skin only.\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1968-10-31\t\t305\t305\t1968\t10\t31\t31 Oct 1968\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNorth America; USA; California; San Francisco Co.\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUSA\t\tCalifornia\tSan Francisco Co.\t\tNear North Lake, Golden Gate Park, San Francisco.\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t37.7700200000\t-122.5014300000\tNAD27\t241\t\t\t37.7700228000\t-122.5014321000\t\t\t\t\tKristina Yamamoto\t2002-12-01\tMaNIS georeferencing guidelines\tTerrain Navigator 5.03 USGS 1:24,000\tunverified\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDouglas J. Long\t2000-05-26\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis pennsylvanicus\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia; Chordata; Mammalia; Rodentia; Sciuridae\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\tpennsylvanicus\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t17\ttotal length\t1\t0.75\t1\tadult\tF\t\tCalifornia Academy of Sciences. CAS Mammalogy (MAM). Source: http://ipt.calacademy.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=mam (source published on 2019-07-23)\t6ce7290f-47f6-4046-8356-371f5b6749df\t66522820-055c-11d8-b84e-b8a03c50a862\tmflannery@calacademy.org\tMaureen Flannery\t2019-07-23\t2019-08-04\tno migrator\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2009-06-05 15:46:10.0\tCC0\t\t\tCalifornia Academy of Sciences. CAS Mammalogy (MAM). Record ID: urn:catalog:CAS:MAM:28420. Source: http://ipt.calacademy.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=mam (source published on 2019-07-23)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cas/mam?id=urn-catalog-cas-mam-28420\t\t\t\tCAS\tMAM\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\tWeight=482.9 g.; Length=455.0 mm.\turn:catalog:CAS:MAM:28420\t28420\t\tUnknown\t\tfemale\tAdult\texternal characters\t\t\t\tTISSUE; SN\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWeight taken on 5 October 1995. Tail: 196.0 mm., HF: 60.0 mm., ear: 26.0 mm.\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1993-08-24\t\t236\t236\t1993\t8\t24\t24 August 1993\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNorth America; USA; California; San Mateo Co.\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUSA\t\tCalifornia\tSan Mateo Co.\t\tRedwood City\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t37.4698300000\t-122.2227100000\tNAD27\t9469\t\t\t37.4698329000\t-122.2227144000\t\t\t\t\tJulian A. Kapoor\t2002-12-22\tMaNIS georeferencing guidelines\tTerrain Navigator 5.03 USGS 1:24,000\tunverified\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia; Chordata; Mammalia; Rodentia; Sciuridae\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t455.0\ttotal length\t0\t482.9\t0\tAdult\tF\t\tCalifornia Academy of Sciences. CAS Mammalogy (MAM). Source: http://ipt.calacademy.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=mam (source published on 2019-07-23)\t6ce7290f-47f6-4046-8356-371f5b6749df\t66522820-055c-11d8-b84e-b8a03c50a862\tmflannery@calacademy.org\tMaureen Flannery\t2019-07-23\t2019-08-04\tno migrator\t0\t1\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2019-08-25 10:42:36.0\thttp://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tChicago Academy of Sciences. CHAS Mammalogy Collection (Arctos). Record ID: http://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:2019.1.74?seid=4307578. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=chas_mammals (source published on 2019-07-07)\thttp://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:2019.1.74\tCHAS\t113\t\tCHAS\tMammal specimens\t\tPreservedSpecimen\tmask part attribute location\t\tverbatim preservation date=2017-12-10 ; sex=male ; total length=504 mm; tail length=219 mm; weight=630 g; fat deposition=subcutaneous fat: heavy\thttp://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:2019.1.74?seid=4307578\tCHAS:Mamm:2019.1.74\t\tCollector(s): Steve Sullivan; Preparator(s): Yuqing Wang\t1\tmale\t\t\t\t\t\tskull; skin, study\t\t\t\t\t\tpreparator number=YW-02\t\thttp://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:2019.1.74\t\t\t\t\t<i>Sciurus carolinensis</i> (accepted ID) identified by Yuqing Wang on 2017-12-10; method: student Remark: Eastern gray squirrel.\t\t\t\t\t2014-11-04\t\t308\t308\t2014\t11\t04\tNov 4 2014\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNorth America, United States, Illinois, Cook County\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\t\tIllinois\tCook County\t\tPeggy Notebaert Nature Museum, 2430 North Cannon Drive, Chicago\tPNNM, Chicago, Cook, IL\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSteve Sullivan\t\t41.926469\t-87.634817\tnot recorded\t131\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSteve Sullivan\t2014-11-04\tGeoLocate\tGeoLocate\tunverified\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tA\t\tYuqing Wang\t2017-12-10\t\tstudent\tEastern gray squirrel.\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia; Chordata; Mammalia; Rodentia; Sciuridae; Sciurinae;\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t504\ttotal length\t0\t630\t0\t\tmale\t\tChicago Academy of Sciences. CHAS Mammalogy Collection (Arctos). Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=chas_mammals (source published on 2019-07-07)\t4837d6b0-19fe-4fe4-9ddf-b62dd17a060e\tf2489500-dbab-4fbc-95ed-19eead127483\tdroberts@naturemuseum.org\tDawn Roberts\t2019-07-07\t2019-09-21\tno migrator\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2019-09-18 16:45:02.0\thttp://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tChicago Academy of Sciences. CHAS Mammalogy Collection (Arctos). Record ID: http://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:3720?seid=4235951. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=chas_mammals (source published on 2019-07-07)\thttp://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:3720\tCHAS\t113\t\tCHAS\tMammal specimens\t\tPreservedSpecimen\tmask part attribute location\t\tverbatim collector=E.V. Komarek ; sex=male ; unformatted measurements=TL: 435, T: 202, HF: 60, Et.: 363g ; total length=435 mm; tail length=202 mm; hind foot with claw=60 mm; weight=363 g\thttp://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:3720?seid=4235951\tCHAS:Mamm:3720\t\tCollector(s): Edwin V. Komarek\t1\tmale\t\t\t\t\t\tskull; skin, study\t\t\t\t\t\tUUID=149e86ee-2118-410f-8248-a0d859201335; secondary identifier=Scc-24\t\"INTERNAL NOTES: collection date listed as January 7, 1936 in Mammal Catalog Book (taped spine), but as \"January 1, 1936\" in 2nd Mammal Catalog Book, needs to be verified [A.King]. DATA HISTORY: Inventory catalogued/verified by Collections staff (2008-2010 inventory). Record last updated in Excel (prior to Arctos migration) by Dawn R. Roberts (2013-11-30). Date listed as entered in original FileMaker database: 1988-07-06.\"\thttp://arctos.database.museum/guid/CHAS:Mamm:3720\t\t\t\t\t<i>Sciurus carolinensis</i> (accepted ID) identified by unknown; method: legacy Remark: Eastern Gray Squirrel.<br><i>Sciurus carolinensis carolinensis</i> identified by unknown; method: legacy\t\t\t\t\t1936-01-01\t\t1\t1\t1936\t01\t01\t[transcribed directly into formatted date fields]\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNorth America, United States, Georgia, Charlton County\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\t\tGeorgia\tCharlton County\t\tChase Prairie, Okefenokee Swamp\tChase Prairie, Okefenokee Swamp, Georgia\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEdwin V. Komarek\tGeoreferenced by John Keating on 16 June 2015 [achinn 20 December 2018].\t30.816062\t-82.226234\tWorld Geodetic System 1984\t2435\t\t30.816062/-82.226234\t\t\tdecimal degrees\t\t\t\tEdwin V. Komarek\t1936-01-01\tGeoLocate\tGeoLocate\tunverified\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tA\t\tunknown\t\t\tlegacy\tEastern Gray Squirrel.\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia; Chordata; Mammalia; Rodentia; Sciuridae; Sciurinae;\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t435\ttotal length\t0\t363\t0\t\tmale\t\tChicago Academy of Sciences. CHAS Mammalogy Collection (Arctos). Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=chas_mammals (source published on 2019-07-07)\t4837d6b0-19fe-4fe4-9ddf-b62dd17a060e\tf2489500-dbab-4fbc-95ed-19eead127483\tdroberts@naturemuseum.org\tDawn Roberts\t2019-07-07\t2019-09-21\tno migrator\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2018-02-28\thttps://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Record ID: 67dd2632-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cumv/mamm?id=67dd2632-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\thttp://grbio.org/cool/i64g-wjcr\thttp://grbio.org/cool/67hr-z96t\t\tCUMV\tMamm\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t{\"hind foot length with claw in mm\":\"62\",\"stomach contents\":\"Masticated nut meats\",\"tail length in mm\":\"200\",\"total length in mm\":\"480\",\"weight\":\"515.3\",\"ear length from notch\":\"31\",\" left gonad length in mm\":\"26\",\" left gonad width in mm\":\"15\",\" right gonad length in mm\":\"26\",\" right gonad width in mm\":\"15\",\"weight unit\":\"g\" }\t67dd2632-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\t16608\t\tDon Schoffler\t\tmale\t\tTestes scrotal\t\t\tpresent\tskeleton\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1993-03-25\t\t84\t84\t1993\t3\t25\t1993-03-25\t\t\t\t\tcollecting method: shot\t\t\tNorth America | United States | New York |  |  |  |  |\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tNew York\t\t\tSchuyler/Tompkins County, Cauyta Township, ~4.5 km ESE of Cayuta, Arnot Forest\tNorth America | United States | New York | Schuyler/Tompkins County, Cauyta Township, ~4.5 km ESE of Cayuta, Arnot Forest\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42.276659\t-76.655259\tWGS84\t3225\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDBCreator\t\t\t\trequires verification\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia | Chordata | Mammalia | Rodentia | Sciuridae | Sciurus\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t480\ttotal length\t0\t515.3\t1\t\tmale\t\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\t35720b3e-aded-4b83-b4f1-967f1d457d6a\tcf9ceb80-9f3d-11da-b791-b8a03c50a862\tcbd63@cornell.edu\tCasey Dillman\t2018-07-02\t2018-07-03\t2018-01-08\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2018-02-28\thttps://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Record ID: 6806d370-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cumv/mamm?id=6806d370-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\thttp://grbio.org/cool/i64g-wjcr\thttp://grbio.org/cool/67hr-z96t\t\tCUMV\tMamm\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t{\"hind foot length with claw in mm\":\"59\",\"tail length in mm\":\"163\",\"total length in mm\":\"440\",\"weight\":\"583.5\",\"ear length from notch\":\"26\",\"weight unit\":\"g\" }\t6806d370-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\t21304\t\tEdward S. Thomas\t\tmale\tadult\tTestes scrotal 22 x 12 mm\t\t\tpresent\tstudy skin - 1; skeleton - 1; tissue (frozen) - 1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2010-04-06\t\t96\t96\t2010\t4\t6\t2010-04-06\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County |  |  |  |\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tNew York\tTompkins\t\tDryden Township, Ellis Hollow\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County | Dryden Township, Ellis Hollow\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42.42766\t-76.38849\tWGS84\t2078\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDBCreator\t2007-06-13\t\t\trequires verification\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia | Chordata | Mammalia | Rodentia | Sciuridae | Sciurus\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t440\ttotal length\t0\t583.5\t1\tadult\tmale\t\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\t35720b3e-aded-4b83-b4f1-967f1d457d6a\tcf9ceb80-9f3d-11da-b791-b8a03c50a862\tcbd63@cornell.edu\tCasey Dillman\t2018-07-02\t2018-07-03\t2018-01-08\t0\t1\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2018-02-28\thttps://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Record ID: 6810ae67-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cumv/mamm?id=6810ae67-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\thttp://grbio.org/cool/i64g-wjcr\thttp://grbio.org/cool/67hr-z96t\t\tCUMV\tMamm\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t{\"hind foot length with claw in mm\":\"64\",\"tail length in mm\":\"230\",\"total length in mm\":\"505\",\"weight\":\"580\",\"weight unit\":\"g\" }\t6810ae67-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\t1832\t\tWilliam J. Hamilton Jr.\t\tmale\tadult\tTestes enlarged & descended\t\t\tpresent\tstudy skin - 1; skull - 1\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRec'd from W.J. Hamilton, Jr.\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1938-10-05\t\t278\t278\t1938\t10\t5\t1938-10-05\t\t\t\t\tcollecting method: killed by car\t\t\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County |  |  |  |\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tNew York\tTompkins\t\tNewfield\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County | Newfield\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42.362018\t-76.590778\tnot recorded (forced WGS84)\t3036\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\trequires verification\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia | Chordata | Mammalia | Rodentia | Sciuridae | Sciurus\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t505\ttotal length\t0\t580\t1\tadult\tmale\t\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\t35720b3e-aded-4b83-b4f1-967f1d457d6a\tcf9ceb80-9f3d-11da-b791-b8a03c50a862\tcbd63@cornell.edu\tCasey Dillman\t2018-07-02\t2018-07-03\t2018-01-08\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2018-03-20\thttps://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Record ID: 681424b0-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cumv/mamm?id=681424b0-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\thttp://grbio.org/cool/i64g-wjcr\thttp://grbio.org/cool/67hr-z96t\t\tCUMV\tMamm\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t{\"hind foot length with claw in mm\":\"71\",\"tail length in mm\":\"208\",\"total length in mm\":\"476\",\"weight\":\"455\",\"weight unit\":\"g\" }\t681424b0-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\t3842\tWJHJ 2460\tWilliam J. Hamilton Jr.\t\tmale\tadult\tTestes small, not descended.\t\t\tpresent\tstudy skin - 1; skull - 1\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSkull broken but saved.  Fleas preserved.; Received from W.J. Hamilton, Jr.\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1947-01-28\t\t28\t28\t1947\t1\t28\t1947-01-28\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County |  |  |  |\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tNew York\tTompkins\t\tIthaca Township, Cayuga Heights, Highland Road\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County | Ithaca Township, Cayuga Heights, Highland Road\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42.465699\t-76.490741\tWGS84\t1488\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDBCreator\t2009-08-26\t\t\trequires verification\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis leucotis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia | Chordata | Mammalia | Rodentia | Sciuridae | Sciurus\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\tleucotis\tsubspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t476\ttotal length\t0\t455\t1\tadult\tmale\t\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\t35720b3e-aded-4b83-b4f1-967f1d457d6a\tcf9ceb80-9f3d-11da-b791-b8a03c50a862\tcbd63@cornell.edu\tCasey Dillman\t2018-07-02\t2018-07-03\t2018-01-08\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2018-02-28\thttps://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Record ID: 68340671-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cumv/mamm?id=68340671-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\thttp://grbio.org/cool/i64g-wjcr\thttp://grbio.org/cool/67hr-z96t\t\tCUMV\tMamm\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t{\"hind foot length with claw in mm\":\"63\",\"tail length in mm\":\"210\",\"total length in mm\":\"405\",\"weight\":\"557\",\"ear length from notch\":\"18\",\" left gonad length in mm\":\"25\",\" left gonad width in mm\":\"15\",\" right gonad length in mm\":\"32\",\" right gonad width in mm\":\"15\",\"weight unit\":\"g\" }\t68340671-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\t17452\t\tDon Schoffler\t\tmale\t\t\t\t\tpresent\tskeleton\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1993-03-25\t\t84\t84\t1993\t3\t25\t1993-03-25\t\t\t\t\tcollecting method: shot\t\t\tNorth America | United States | New York |  |  |  |  |\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tNew York\t\t\tSchuyler/Tompkins County, Cauyta Township, ~4.5 km ESE of Cayuta, Arnot Forest\tNorth America | United States | New York | Schuyler/Tompkins County, Cauyta Township, ~4.5 km ESE of Cayuta, Arnot Forest\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42.276659\t-76.655259\tWGS84\t3225\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDBCreator\t\t\t\trequires verification\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia | Chordata | Mammalia | Rodentia | Sciuridae | Sciurus\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t405\ttotal length\t0\t557\t1\t\tmale\t\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\t35720b3e-aded-4b83-b4f1-967f1d457d6a\tcf9ceb80-9f3d-11da-b791-b8a03c50a862\tcbd63@cornell.edu\tCasey Dillman\t2018-07-02\t2018-07-03\t2018-01-08\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2018-02-28\thttps://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Record ID: 6834ab99-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cumv/mamm?id=6834ab99-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\thttp://grbio.org/cool/i64g-wjcr\thttp://grbio.org/cool/67hr-z96t\t\tCUMV\tMamm\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t{\"hind foot length with claw in mm\":\"62\",\"tail length in mm\":\"220\",\"total length in mm\":\"465\",\"weight\":\"536\",\"ear length from notch\":\"32\",\"weight unit\":\"g\" }\t6834ab99-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\t18586\t\tDora E. Worbs\t\tfemale\t\t\t\t\tpresent\tstudy skin - 1; skeleton - 1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1995-11-02\t\t306\t306\t1995\t11\t2\t1995-11-02\t\t\t\t\tcollecting method: killed by cat\t\t\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County |  |  |  |\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tNew York\tTompkins\t\tCaroline Township, White Church & Ridgeway Roads, ~4.3 km S Brooktondale\tNorth America | United States | New York | Tompkins County | Caroline Township, White Church & Ridgeway Roads, ~4.3 km S Brooktondale\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42.3443\t-76.3857\tWGS84\t112\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDBCreator\t2009-01-26\t\t\trequires verification\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia | Chordata | Mammalia | Rodentia | Sciuridae | Sciurus\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t465\ttotal length\t0\t536\t1\t\tfemale\t\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\t35720b3e-aded-4b83-b4f1-967f1d457d6a\tcf9ceb80-9f3d-11da-b791-b8a03c50a862\tcbd63@cornell.edu\tCasey Dillman\t2018-07-02\t2018-07-03\t2018-01-08\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1", "PhysicalObject\t2018-02-28\thttps://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/\t\thttp://vertnet.org/resources/norms.html\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Record ID: 68384b01-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\thttp://portal.vertnet.org/o/cumv/mamm?id=68384b01-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\thttp://grbio.org/cool/i64g-wjcr\thttp://grbio.org/cool/67hr-z96t\t\tCUMV\tMamm\t\tPreservedSpecimen\t\t\t{\"hind foot length with claw in mm\":\"70\",\"stomach contents\":\"Empty\",\"tail length in mm\":\"233\",\"total length in mm\":\"475\",\"weight\":\"512\",\"ear length from notch\":\"31\",\"weight unit\":\"g\" }\t68384b01-537e-11e6-9649-a4a3446a4726\t17444\t\tunknown\t\tfemale\t\tShrunken, abdominal\t\t\tpresent\tskeleton\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1994-03-23\t\t82\t82\t1994\t3\t23\t1994-03-23\t\t\t\t\tcollecting method: shot\t\t\tNorth America | United States | New York |  |  |  |  |\tNorth America\t\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tNew York\t\t\tSchuyler/Tompkins County, Cauyta Township, ~4.5 km ESE of Cayuta, Arnot Forest\tNorth America | United States | New York | Schuyler/Tompkins County, Cauyta Township, ~4.5 km ESE of Cayuta, Arnot Forest\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42.276659\t-76.655259\tWGS84\t3225\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDBCreator\t\t\t\trequires verification\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSciurus carolinensis\t\t\t\t\tAnimalia | Chordata | Mammalia | Rodentia | Sciuridae | Sciurus\tAnimalia\tChordata\tMammalia\tRodentia\tSciuridae\tSciurus\t\tcarolinensis\t\tspecies\t\t\t\tICZN\t\t\t475\ttotal length\t0\t512\t1\t\tfemale\t\tCornell University Museum of Vertebrates. CUMV Mammal Collection. Source: http://ipt.vertnet.org:8080/ipt/resource.do?r=cumv_mamm (source published on 2018-07-02)\t35720b3e-aded-4b83-b4f1-967f1d457d6a\tcf9ceb80-9f3d-11da-b791-b8a03c50a862\tcbd63@cornell.edu\tCasey Dillman\t2018-07-02\t2018-07-03\t2018-01-08\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\tspecimen\t1")
```

Below is the code I used to load the .txt file and create the 13 column data frame.

```
setwd()

install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
install.packages("cowplot")
library(cowplot)

Sciurus_carolinensis_total <- readr::read_tsv("Sciurus_carolinensis_total.txt") %>% select(genus, specificepithet, sex, year, month, day, countrycode, stateprovince, county, decimallatitude, decimallongitude, lengthinmm, lengthtype)
```

Thank you for the help. It was far more simple a solution than I thought.

Comment: I've suggested an edit that (imo) makes this question much less daunting: long long questions, due to verbose descriptions (or rambling) is one thing, but long mis-formatted data is another. Code is not the only thing that can (and should) go in code-blocks, data does quite well in them as well.

Comment: If this is the actual (raw) format of the file, then I don't think a parser out-of-the-box is going to work well. There's no clear delimiter (other than variable blank-space), so the first data-row missing its modified timestamp is a problem, as we cannot not authoritatively that it is missing (without pattern matching, etc. If VertNet has a better-defined format (e.g., json, xml, csv, tsv), then it might be better to work with those than this. (It's entirely possible, too, that the Stack site here is masking tabs as spaces, which might assist. For that, we might need your clarification.)

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the suggested edit to my post. I will make sure to do that in the future.

Comment: The data downloaded from VertNet is only downloaded as a text document which I believe is tab delimited. Does that help? There isn't a way to upload a text document to this site for analysis is there?

Comment: It does, and now that I look more I see that the Stack interface is defeating things a little: when I edit your question to look at the raw data, it does appear to have tabs, but rendered into HTML it does not. I don't think it's realistic to expect users to have to edit your question to get the data, so I just suggested an edit that adds most (12 of 15) of your raw lines and still stays within Stack's 30K character limit.

Comment: Thank you! I added the code to read the .txt file that I will try above. Could you or someone else see if that is what you meant?

Comment: Showing `read.delim` can be useful to show what options you chose, yes, though the actual filename is immaterial (since we don't have it). If you have a URL, sometimes that helps, though I believe some (many?) will not click on the URL so having the sample data *also* is preferable.

Comment: Please confirm (in the question) that you're using `readr::read_tsv` or whichever package that comes from (it isn't base R). Also, are you really using `select(..., c("type\tmodified\tlicense\t..."))`? The `c("...")` in a `select` does not make sense here.

Comment: I can't believe it took me this long to see the problem. **Don't use `c(...)` in `select`**. After loading it, just do `select(Sciurus_carolinensis_total, genus, specificepithet, sex, year, month, ...)`. No extra parens, no `c(.)`.

Comment: Granted ... `select(..., c(...))` can still work, but it isn't really necessary. Various versions of your question I've seen had data-like strings in there and various other strings, not entirely sure what they were. Bottom line, I can read in that data and find 174 columns for each row with no error, and `select(...)` just fine.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for your help